How many diffraction lines do the images of Swift and Fermi have?
How many diffraction lines does the swift and fermi telescopes have? An example of what I am looking for is an image showing these clear diffraction lines, like this one from JWST:

How many diffraction lines do the Swift and Fermi telescopes have, and are there any clear images showing these lines?
Edit: For Swift and Fermi ideally it'd be all the instruments onboard, if applicable.

Which specific telescopes on the spacecraft are you asking about? (E.g., Swift has two imaging telescopes: XRT and UVOT.)

Oh good catch, ideally it would be all of the instruments if possible. I'll edit my question

Diffraction is a negligible contributor to the point spread functions of x-ray and gamma ray telescopes. The artifacts that look a bit like diffraction spikes in the Swift XRT PSF are the result of slight distortions of the thin mirror shells due to stress at the support points.

What about UVOT?

@John Doty, do you have anything for the UVOT?
